# Why is salt unable to set pear configuration?

Tags: php, shell, pear, salt-stack

I am trying to set pear configuration to point to the correct php.ini file.  The state is running, but when I use pear config-get php_ini to check if the value is set, I see

[Tue Aug 01 06:17:39] root@xxx:~# sudo pear config-get php_ini

[Tue Aug 01 06:17:43] root@xxx:~#

The first attempt

```
php-pear-config-set:
  cmd.run:
    - name: pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
    - unless: false
```

If I direct the output to a file, it shows that it was successful, but when I check the config, it is still empty.

The second attempt

```
php-pear-config-set:
  cmd.run:
    - name: pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini > /tmp/test.txt
    - unless: false
```

The contents of the test.txt file

```
config-set succeeded
~
```

If I run pear config-show and look for the config file, I see the following

```
User Configuration File        Filename         /root/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear.conf
```

When I look for /etc/pear.conf there is none.

If I run on the minion from the console

```
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Then look at the file /etc/pear.conf, the file still doesn't exist.

But if I look at the file /root/.pearrc, the contents show.

```
#PEAR_Config 0.9
a:1:{s:7:"php_ini";s:28:"/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini";}
```

The permissions of /root/.pearrc

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 Aug  1 17:23 /root/.pearrc
```

I just read the following, "The pear.conf is used by PEAR applications to store their configuration. This file should not be edited."
https://www.mankier.com/5/pear.conf

Comment: If you run pear config-show | grep "System Config" it should show you the location of the pear config file.  Typically it's /etc/pear.conf.  Who is the owner and what are the perms of that file?  Perhaps the pear.conf file isn't actually being written.

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Why don't you add a touch /etc/pear.conf to your configuration if the file doesn't exist.  Seems like that explains why this isn't working.